# PROVISIONING SAMBA

Tags: networking, server, samba, domain-server

I installed Samba on my Ubuntu server but at the **PROVISIONING** step there was a problem like this.

```
superuser@dww:~$ sudo samba-tool domain provision
  Realm [DWW-JO.LOCAL]: DWW-JO.LOCAL
    Domain [DWW-JO]: DWW-JO
 Server Role (dc, member, standalone) [dc]: dc
 DNS backend (SAMBA_INTERNAL, BIND9_FLATFILE, BIND9_DLZ, NONE) [SAMBA_INTERNAL]: BIND9_DLZ
Administrator password: 
Retype password: 
Sorry, passwords do not match.
Administrator password: 
Retype password: 
Looking up IPv4 addresses
Looking up IPv6 addresses
No IPv6 address will be assigned
ERROR(<type 'exceptions.IOError'>): uncaught exception - [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/samba/setup/ad-schema/MS-AD_Schema_2K8_R2_Attributes.txt'
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/netcmd/__init__.py", line 176, in _run
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/netcmd/domain.py", line 474, in run
    nosync=ldap_backend_nosync, ldap_dryrun_mode=ldap_dryrun_mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py", line 2080, in provision
    schemadn=names.schemadn)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/schema.py", line 88, in __init__
    setup_path('ad-schema/MS-AD_Schema_2K8_R2_Classes.txt'))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/ms_schema.py", line 275, in read_ms_schema
    attr_ldif =  __parse_schema_file(attr_file, "attributeSchema")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/ms_schema.py", line 261, in __parse_schema_file
    f = open(filename, "rU")
```

how to solve it? Thank you

**Ubuntu Server 18.04
samba version 4.10.2**

Comment: what do you believe this means "No such file or directory: '/usr/share/samba/setup/ad-schema/MS-AD_Schema_2K8_R2_Attributes.txt'"? You probably did not follow the instructions? do you have that file? if so did you add samba to your PATH?

Comment: hello @rinzwind, thanks for  your help
I found it in the directory `/home/superuser/samba-4.10.2/source4/setup/ad-schema/MS-AD_Schema_2K8_Attributes.txt`  and `/usr/local/samba/share/setup/ad-schema/MS-AD_Schema_2K8_Attributes.txt`

So, what should I do?

Comment: How did you install samba? What is the output of `which smbd`?

Comment: @suhartiman you probably need to add samba to your PATH. https://lists.samba.org/archive/samba/2016-January/197144.html is about the same issue.

Comment: hey @vidarlo this is location my samba installation `/usr/local/samba/sbin//smbd'. 

sory I am a beginner to use ubuntu and samba. many thanks

Comment: hey @Rinzwind this file contents
`/etc/environment`
  `PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/samba/bin:/usr/local/samba/sbin"`

`/etc/sudoers`
`Defaults        env_reset`
`Defaults        mail_badpass`
`Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin:/usr/local/samba/sbin:/usr/local/samba/bin"`